# ConfigurationProperties - how to create configuration with groups and default property values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot application and Java8.

**The problem description**

The most general need is to create Java represention of multiple my.externalsystem.connection properties and group them with usage of @ConfigurationProperties annotation. I have application.properties file which currently is missing any `my.externalsystem.connection` property to simulate wrong configuration (someone forgot to place property in properties file and the default property values should be then used). The specific property which is missing is `my.externalsystem.connection.enabled=false (default should be true)` There will be more properties with prefix `my.externalsystem.connection` in future.

Because there will be many `my.externalsystem.connection` properties, I would create property group like in Java object below:

**My Java class representing properties:**

```
@Configuration
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.externalsystem")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyConfiguration {

    private ConnectionProperties connection;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ConnectionProperties {
        public ConnectionProperties (@DefaultValue("true") boolean enabled) {
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }
        private boolean enabled;
    }
}
```

**The problem in runtime**

When I run it with `my.externalsystem.connection.enabled=true or false` in properties file, it properly reads the value and everything works fine. However, when `my.externalsystem.connection.enabled` is missing in properties file, the `connection` object is null in runtime. Why it is not created with default values? I need this class to work with default values (true for `my.externalsystem.connection.enabled` is the default value).

Can somebody help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a default constructor for `ConnectionProperties` to instantiate the class and map the properties if missing.

Not sure if or how this could be translated to Lombok somehow with `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor`, but this should work:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.externalsystem")
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyConfiguration {

    private ConnectionProperties connection = new ConnectionProperties();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class ConnectionProperties {
        private boolean enabled;

        public ConnectionProperties() {
            this.enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

In this example if the property is missing it will just use the default value from the constructor and will override it if the property is present.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this solution but I had an impression that it would not be best practice. I was wondering if I could do something similar to known pattern which is used in @Value annotation. In normal flat properties u do @Value("${my.externalsystem.connection.enabled:true}") where `true` after colon means the default value and u don't have to set it in constructor.

Comment: You should let Spring create the `ConnectionProperties` instance and let it put it into the application context. In a Spring application, never create instances, that should be managed, yourself.

Comment: Yup, you're right @Seelenvirtuose. I got too focused on the specific question OP posted, but generally speaking in that case the whole `MyConfiguration` outer class could just be removed and `ConnectionProperties` annotated with @Component and autowired where needed

Comment: There is @Component in MyConfiguration class, I added it I had it in code already but somehow it was missing in my post, the rest of the post is valid. This does not change anything, I am am not sure how to tell Spring to create MyConfiguration with default value (equal true) for my parameter when the my.externalsystem.connection.enabled is not present in application.properties. Can u provide some example ? And why your answer was marked -1 ?